# Reading data from a file in python, but taking specific data from the file throughout

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to read data from a .dat file, the file has information like this:

```
1
Carmella Henderson
24.52
13.5
21.76
2
Christal Piper
14.98
11.01
21.75
3
Erma Park
12.11
13.51
18.18
4
Dorita Griffin
20.05
10.39
21.35
5 
Marlon Holmes
18.86
13.02
13.36
```

From this data I need the person number, name and the first number, like so:

```
1 #person number
Marlon Holmes  #Name
18.86 # First number
13.02
13.36
```

However currently my code is reading the data from the file but not these specific parts, it is simply printing the file

This is my code currently for this specific part:

```
def Cucumber_Scoreboard():
    with open('veggies_2015.dat', 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        for line in f:
            count **= 1
            if count % 2 == 0:
                print (line)
```

Im not sure where it's going wrong, I tried to put the data from the file into a list and try it from there but had no success, any help would be greatly appreciated

Whole file code if needed:

```
def menu():
    exit = False


    while not exit:
        print("To enter new competitior data, type new")
        print("To view the competition score boards, type Scoreboard")
        print("To view the Best Overall Growers Scoreboard, type Podium")
        print("To review this years and previous data, type Data review")
        print("Type quit to exit the program")

        choice = raw_input("Which option would you like?")

        if choice == 'new':
            new_competitor()
        elif choice == 'Scoreboard':
            scoreboard_menu()
        elif choice == 'Podium':
            podium_place()
        elif choice == 'Data review':
            data_review()
        elif choice == 'quit':
            print("Goodbye")
            raise SystemExit

"""Entering new competitor data: record competitor's name and vegtables lengths"""

def competitor_data():
    global competitor_num
    l = []

    print("How many competitors would you like to enter?")

    competitors = raw_input("Number of competitors:")

    num_competitors = int(competitors)

    for i in range(num_competitors):

        name = raw_input("Enter competitor name:")
        Cucumber = raw_input("Enter length of Cucumber:")
        Carrot = raw_input("Enter length of Carrot:")
        Runner_Beans = raw_input("Enter length of Runner Beans:")

        l.append(competitor_num)
        l.append(name)
        l.append(Cucumber)
        l.append(Carrot)
        l.append(Runner_Beans)

        competitor_num += 1

    return (l)



def new_competitor():
    with open('veggies_2016.txt', 'a') as f:
        for item in competitor_data():
            f.write("%s\n" %(item))



def scoreboard_menu():
    exit = False

    print("Which vegetable would you like the scoreboard for?")

    vegetable = raw_input("Please type either Cucumber, Carrot or Runner Beans:")

    if vegetable == "Cucumber":
        Cucumber_Scoreboard()
    elif vegetable == "Carrot":
        Carrot_Scoreboard()
    elif vegetable == "Runner Beans":
        Runner_Beans_Scoreboard()

def Cucumber_Scoreboard():
    with open('veggies_2015.dat', 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        for line in f:
            count **= 1
            if count % 2 == 0:
                print (line)
```

Comment: `count **= 1 == count` (you're raising `count` to the power of 1. It effectively never changes). `**` is exponentation, `*` is multiplication

Comment: changing count to 
count += 1

That makes it print every other line from the file

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was your intention and you simply made a typo since `value % 2 == 0` is a classical way of getting every second number or all even numbers

Comment: I think a more structured data format would serve you well. Sure, you could keep counting lines and use modulo to get every Nth player's stats, but I always use and recommend json and python dictionaries instead. It's pretty easy and there's a module for it (`import json`). That way, spaces don't matter and everything could be written on one line. You get and set values via keywords instead. It would also make it easier to transmit the data via the web later on, should you feel like it.

Comment: That sounds good however i have no experience with json

Comment: Ok, I've written an answer that demonstrates how it could be used to save/load scores in a game. Maybe you could adapt it to fit your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't feel the most elegant way of doing it, but if you're going line by line, you need an extra counter in there which results in nothing happening for a set amount of "surplus" lines, before resetting your counters. Note that `excess_count` only needs to be incremented once because you want the final `else` to reset both counters, again which will not result in something being printed but still results in a skipped line.

```
def Cucumber_Scoreboard():
    with open('name_example.txt', 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        excess_count = 0
        for line in f:
            if count < 3:
                print (line)
                count += 1
            elif count == 3 and excess_count < 1:
                excess_count += 1
            else:
                count = 0
                excess_count = 0
```

EDIT: Based on your comments, I have extended this answer. Really, what you have asked should be raised as another question because it is detached from your main question. As pointed out by jDo, this is not ideal code because it will fail instantly if there is a blank line or missing data causing a line to skip artificially. Also, the new code is stuffed in around my initial answer. Use this only as an illustration of resetting counters and lists in loops, it's not stable for serious things.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def Cucumber_Scoreboard():
    with open('name_example.txt', 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        excess_count = 0
        complete_person_list = []
        sublist = []

        for line in f:
            if count < 3:
                print (line)
                sublist.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
                count += 1
            elif count == 3 and excess_count < 1:
                excess_count += 1
            else:
                count = 0
                excess_count = 0
                complete_person_list.append(sublist)
                sublist = []

        sorted_list = sorted(complete_person_list, key=itemgetter(2), reverse = True)
    return sorted_list

a = Cucumber_Scoreboard()
```

Comment: This works great! Would there be a way to get the top 10 from this?

Comment: @NeilHouston Glad it helped. You'll have to clarify "top 10" for me though. The first 10 entries of 3 values e.g. ending on `10, name, value`?

Comment: the top 10 should be from data that the code brings out, 

1 #person number
Marlon Holmes  #Name
18.86 # First number

So it would be like what are the top 10 highest numbers from #First number , but it would need the corresponding data with it like #person number and #name

hope that makes sense

Comment: @roganjosh I know this might be an answer to OP's question but wouldn't the whole thing collapse if someone accidentally introduced an empty line or an extra line of data somewhere? Relying on line numbers and counting seems awfully brittle

Comment: @jDo Yep, and in building an answer for the extension of the question (which is less relevant to the question itself) I feel I'm veering off into really poor code. I will clarify in my edit shortly; from the nature of the question I think it's more of a demo for the fundamentals of how loops work in Python

Comment: @NeilHouston I have made the edit. In .dat files maybe you don't need to `.replace(\n, '')`, I was just verifying with a .txt file before writing the answer. You can use list slicing, such as `a[0:10]` to get the top 10 people.  Take note of jDo's comments and my caution with this code though. If you find that this answer solved your problem, I would be grateful if you could click the tick next to it to close the question :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, you have solved my question :)

Comment: @roganjosh Cool cool, good thing you pointed out the problems associated with the current data format

Answer (score 0):

You could make the program read the whole file line by line getting all the information.  Then because the data is in a known format (eg position, name ...) skip the unneeded lines with file.readline() which will move you to the next line.

Comment: ideally what would be great if i could read the first 3 lines then skip 2 then read the next 3 again and so on

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that reads one "record" (5 lines) at a time, then call it repeatedly:

```
def read_data(in_file):
    rec = {}
    rec["num"] = in_file.next().strip()
    rec["name"] = in_file.next().strip()
    rec["cucumber"] = float(in_file.next().strip())

    # skip 2 lines
    in_file.next()
    in_file.next()

    return rec
```

*EDIT: improved the code + added a usage example*

The `read_data()` function reads one 5-line record from a file and returns its data as a dictionary. An example of using this function:

```
def Cucumber_Scoreboard():
    with open('veggies_2015.dat', 'r') as in_file:
        data = []

        try:
            while True:
                rec = read_data(in_file)
                data.append(rec)

        except StopIteration:
            pass

    data_sorted = sorted(data, key = lambda x: x["cucumber"])

    return data_sorted

cucumber = Cucumber_Scoreboard()

from pprint import pprint
pprint(cucumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone recently asked how to save the player scores for his/her game and I ended up writing a quick demo. I didn't post it though since it would be a little *too* helpful. In its current form, it doesn't fit your game exactly but maybe you can use it for inspiration. Whatever you do, not relying on line numbers, modulo and counting will  save you a headache down the line (what if someone added an empty/extra line?).

There are advantages and drawbacks associated with all datatypes. If we compare your current data format (newline separated values with no keys or category/column labels) to json, yours is actually more efficient in terms of space usage. You don't have any repetitions. In key/value pair formats like json and python dictionaries, you often repeat the keys over and over again. This makes it a human-readable format, it makes order insignificant and it means that the entire thing could be written on a single line. However, it goes without saying that repeating all the keys for every player is not efficient. If there were 100.000 players and they all had a firstname, lastname, highscore and last_score, you'd be repeating these 4 words 100.000 times. This is where actual databases become the sane choice for data storage. In your case though, I think json will suffice.

```
import json
import pprint

def scores_load(scores_json_file):
    """ you hand this function a filename and it returns a dictionary of scores """
    with open(scores_json_file, "r") as scores_json:
        return json.loads(scores_json.read())

def scores_save(scores_dict, scores_json_file):
    """ you hand this function a dictionary and a filename to save the scores """
    with open(scores_json_file, "w") as scores_json:
        scores_json.write(json.dumps(scores_dict)) 

# main dictionary of dictionaries - empty at first
scores_dict = {}

# a single player stat dictionary. 
# add/remove keys and values at will
scores_dict["player1"] = {
    "firstname" : "whatever",
    "lastname" : "whateverson",
    "last_score" : 3,
    "highscore" : 12,
}

# another player stat dictionary
scores_dict["player2"] = {
    "firstname" : "something",
    "lastname" : "somethington",
    "last_score" : 5,
    "highscore" : 15,
}


# here, we save the main dictionary containing stats 
# for both players in a json file called scores.json
scores_save(scores_dict, "scores.json")

# here, we load them again and turn them into a 
# dictionary that we can easily read and write to
scores_dict = scores_load("scores.json")

# add a third player 
scores_dict["player3"] = {
    "firstname" : "person",
    "lastname" : "personton",
    "last_score" : 2,
    "highscore" : 3,
}

# save the whole thing again
scores_save(scores_dict, "scores.json")

# print player2's highscore
print scores_dict["player2"]["highscore"]

# we can also invent a new category (key/value pair) on the fly if we want to
# it doesn't have to exist for every player
scores_dict["player2"]["disqualified"] = True

# print the scores dictionary in a pretty/easily read format.
# this isn't necessary but just looks nicer
pprint.pprint(scores_dict)

"""
The contents of the scores.json pretty-printed in my terminal:

$ cat scores.json | json_pp

{
   "player3" : {
      "firstname" : "person",
      "last_score" : 2,
      "lastname" : "personton",
      "highscore" : 3
   },
   "player2" : {
      "highscore" : 15,
      "lastname" : "somethington",
      "last_score" : 5,
      "firstname" : "something"
   },
   "player1" : {
      "firstname" : "whatever",
      "last_score" : 3,
      "lastname" : "whateverson",
      "highscore" : 12
   }
}


"""
```